# Obtaining MP3 Audio Compression Library

Tags: audio, compression, operating-system, mp3

I would like to find out where I would be able to find the MP3 library, for implementation in an Operating System.

Comment: I wonder how MP3 can be part of the core of an OS... Beside, there are better sound compression systems, free of patents/licenses! (Eg. Ogg Vobis.)

Comment: To enable developers to call API's to assist with MP3 operations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for [Lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 4):

One note: MP3 encoding is covered by patents held by the Fraunhofer Institute and Thomson Multimedia. If the Operating System you are working on is more than just a hobby for your own use, you should think about patent issues and [licensing](http://www.mp3licensing.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want an officially-licensed MP3 library, you probably ought to contact [Thompson](http://www.mp3licensing.com), who are handling patent licensing for Fraunhofer.